# How can I get CSR from signature key pair

Tags: c++, cryptography, window, x509certificate2, cng

Based on [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/example-c-program-creating-a-key-container-and-generating-keys), I have successfully created the signature key pair and Key Container.
The key container after creation will be stored in **%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA** folder.

Next, I want to use signature key pair to get CSR(certificate signing request). So how do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48196350/238704

Answer (score 0):

1. Get NCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE key handle with NCryptOpenKey if use CNG
   (or get HCRYPTPROV handle with CryptAcquireContext if use CAPI);
2. Export public key with [CryptExportPublicKeyInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptexportpublickeyinfo);
3. Encode subject name with [CertStrToName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certstrtonamea), for example:

```cpp
    DWORD EncodeCertificateName(const std::wstring& name_to_encode, const DWORD delim_flag, 
        std::vector<BYTE>& encoded_name)
    {
        DWORD encoded_name_len = 0;
        /* get length */
        if (!CertStrToName(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,
            name_to_encode.data(),
            CERT_X500_NAME_STR | delim_flag,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            &encoded_name_len,
            NULL))
        {
            return GetLastError();
        }
    
        encoded_name.resize(encoded_name_len);
        /* encode */
        if (!CertStrToName(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,
            name_to_encode.data(),
            CERT_X500_NAME_STR | delim_flag,
            NULL,
            encoded_name.data(),
            &encoded_name_len,
            NULL))
        {
            return GetLastError();
        }
    
        return ERROR_SUCCESS;
    }
    
    std::wstring subject = L"CN=Test_request, E=test@test.com";
    std::vector<BYTE> encoded_name;
    EncodeCertificateName(subject, CERT_NAME_STR_COMMA_FLAG, &encoded_name);
```

4. Fill [CERT_REQUEST_INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/ns-wincrypt-cert_request_info) structure:

```cpp
    CERT_REQUEST_INFO cert_req_info;
    
    /* set attributes if any */
    cert_req_info.cAttribute = 0;
    cert_req_info.rgAttribute = nullptr;
    
    cert_req_info.dwVersion = CERT_REQUEST_V1;
    
    /* set encoded subject name */
    cert_req_info.Subject.cbData = static_cast<DWORD>(name_enc.size());
    cert_req_info.Subject.pbData = name_enc.data();
    
    /* set exported public key info */
    cert_req_info.SubjectPublicKeyInfo = pub_key_info;
```

5. Fill CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER structure:

```cpp
    CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER sig_alg;
    
    /* set signature algorithm, for example */ 
    sig_alg.pszObjId = szOID_RSA_SHA256RSA;
```

6. Create certificate request with [CryptSignAndEncodeCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptsignandencodecertificate) and parameter lpszStructType = X509_CERT_REQUEST_TO_BE_SIGNED:

```cpp
std::vector<BYTE> enc_req_val;
DWORD enc_req_len = 0;
/* get length */
if (!CryptSignAndEncodeCertificate(hProv,
    AT_SIGNATURE, 
    PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING | X509_ASN_ENCODING,
    X509_CERT_REQUEST_TO_BE_SIGNED,
    &cert_req_info,
    &sig_alg,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    &enc_req_len))
{
    /* handle error */
}

enc_req_val.resize(enc_req_len);
/* create certificate request */
if (!CryptSignAndEncodeCertificate(hProv,
    AT_SIGNATURE, 
    PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING | X509_ASN_ENCODING,
    X509_CERT_REQUEST_TO_BE_SIGNED,
    &cert_req_info,
    &sig_alg,
    nullptr,
    enc_req_val.data(),
    &enc_req_len))
{
    /* handle error */
}
```