# Create RSA key from RSACryptoServiceProvider?

Tags: c#, cryptography, certificate, rsa, cng

I want to use the key I created via CSP (I use Utimaco interface 'CSP Tool'),
to generate the CA certificate, I use this code (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48210587/6197785)):

```
var csp = new CspParameters()
{
    ProviderName = "Utimaco CryptoServer CSP",
    ProviderType = 1,
    KeyContainerName = "Default Container"
};

RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024, csp);
RSAParameters myRSA = rsaProvider.ExportParameters(false);
using (RSA parent = RSA.Create(myRSA))
using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create(2048))
{
    CertificateRequest parentReq = new CertificateRequest(
        "CN=Experimental Issuing Authority",
        parent,
        HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
        RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

    parentReq.CertificateExtensions.Add(
        new X509BasicConstraintsExtension(true, false, 0, true));

    parentReq.CertificateExtensions.Add(
        new X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension(parentReq.PublicKey, false));

    using (X509Certificate2 parentCert = parentReq.CreateSelfSigned(
        DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(-45),
        DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(365)))
    {
        CertificateRequest req = new CertificateRequest(
            "CN=Valid-Looking Timestamp Authority",
            rsa,
            HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
            RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

        req.CertificateExtensions.Add(
            new X509BasicConstraintsExtension(false, false, 0, false));

        req.CertificateExtensions.Add(
            new X509KeyUsageExtension(
                System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature |
                System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyUsageFlags.NonRepudiation,
                false));

        req.CertificateExtensions.Add(
            new X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension(
                new OidCollection
                {
        new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.8")
                },
                true));

        req.CertificateExtensions.Add(
            new X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension(req.PublicKey, false));

        using (X509Certificate2 cert = req.Create(
            parentCert,
            DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(-1),
            DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(90),
            new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }))
        {
            // Do something with these certs, like export them to PFX,
            // or add them to an X509Store, or whatever.
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
            store.Add(cert);
            store.Add(parentCert);
            store.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

It throws: **System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Key does not exist.'** at the `parentReq.CreateSelfSigned(..)` call.

This is the key info:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 RSAParameters myRSA = rsaProvider.ExportParameters(false);
 using (RSA parent = RSA.Create(myRSA))
```

This makes `parent` be just the public key portion, which means it can't sign certificates.

Assuming you want the CA certificate to know about its private key, just use `rsaProvider` instead of exporting/importing into `parent`.  (Either `RSA parent = rsaProvider;` or just replace all usage of `parent` with `rsaProvider`)