# Incorrect Generation of Certificates from RSA keypair

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, cryptography, x509

I have been generating certificates for my TCP client/server using [mbedtls' gen_key/cert_write tools](https://tls.mbed.org/kb/cryptography/rsa-key-pair-generator), and openssl to generate the .pfx file for the server. This works fine, but was only for test purposes. Now, I woud like to generate these certificates programmatically. In the below code, I create an RSA keypair and then create the client(root ca) certificate and the server .pfx file. The handshake never ends up going through, however, despite the client and server both loading the root cert and the .pfx respectively without any apparent errors.

```
private void GenerateCertificate()
{
    if (!Directory.Exists("cert"))
    {
        RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
    
         CertificateRequest rootRequest = new CertificateRequest("CN=localhost", rsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
                        RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
    
         rootRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509BasicConstraintsExtension(true, false, 0, true));
    
         rootRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension(rootRequest.PublicKey, false));
    
         using (X509Certificate2 rootCert = rootRequest.CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(-45), 
                        DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(365)))
         {
             //File.WriteAllText("cert\\private.key", new string(PemEncoding.Write("RSA PRIVATE KEY", rootcert.GetRSAPrivateKey().ExportRSAPrivateKey())));
             //File.WriteAllText("cert\\private.key", new string(PemEncoding.Write("RSA PUBLIC KEY", rootcert.GetRSAPrivateKey().ExportRSAPrivateKey())));
    
             CertificateRequest serverRequest = new CertificateRequest("CN=localhost", rsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
                            RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
    
             serverRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509BasicConstraintsExtension(false, false, 0, false));
    
             serverRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509KeyUsageExtension(X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature | 
                            X509KeyUsageFlags.NonRepudiation, false));
    
             serverRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension( new OidCollection { new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.8") }, 
                            true));
    
             serverRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension(serverRequest.PublicKey, false));
    
             using (X509Certificate2 serverCert = serverRequest.Create(rootCert, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(-1),
                            DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(90), new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }))
             {
                 // For clients
                 File.WriteAllText("cert\\certificate.crt", new string(PemEncoding.Write("CERTIFICATE",
                                rootCert.Export(X509ContentType.Cert))));
    
                 // For Server
                 File.WriteAllBytes("cert\\server.pfx", serverCert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx));
             }
         }
     }
                
              /****/
 }
```

Comment: serverCert does not have a private key, therefore `server.pfx` also lacks a private key. I don't know how to fix this because I'm not an expert in .Net and 10 minutes of noodling around the API accomplished nothing except to give me a headache. Good luck.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Found this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69717028

Seemed to fix it, but I now have another error about the 'usage not matching the extendedKeyUsage extension'. At least it finally connects now.

Comment: It's also worth noting that your root and server cert use the same private key.  You probably want to use two different ones.

Comment: Your "server" cert has the EKU 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.8, which means it's claiming to be a cryptographic timestamp server.  Change the 8 to a 1 (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1).  Now it's claiming to be a TLS server.

Comment: @bartonjs Thank you for your comments. Those solved the remaining issue!